# Is this circular linked list better than the fast & slow pointer method?

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

I have a faster way to find if a list is circular linked list, in contrast to the [solution](https://github.com/gaylemcd/ctci/blob/master/java/Chapter%202/Question2_6/Question.java) that [*Cracking the Coding Interview*](http://www.crackingthecodinginterview.com/) has offered:

In the below algorithm, `fast-pointer` will either hit null (in case of linear list) or hit starting point/origin (in case of circular) quicker than conventional (fast & slow pointer approach).

Reason: because in fast & slow pointer approach, we wait for the `fastPointer == slowPointer` condition to determine if it's a circular list. But `fastPointer` would reach its origin/starting point first before hitting slow pointer. (what's the point of crossing over the starting point and continuing the hunt for `slowPointer`?)

Isn't the below example a better algorithm?  If so, then why have a fast & slow pointer approach?

(I didn't consider starting point as "node outside of loop" scenario while asking question.)

```
public boolean findCircular(Node someRandomNodeOfList) {

    Node fast = someRandomNodeOfList;
    while (true) {
        if ((fast.next == null) || (fast.next.next == null)) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (fast.next == someRandomNodeOfList|| fast.next.next == someRandomNodeOfList) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            fast = fast.next.next;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think you're making a faulty assumption: that the circular portion of a looped linked list includes the list's head.

Comment: Even if its not a head, I would store starting point as say root. and then if I reach my starting point I conclude it is circular list.. right?

Comment: if loop in list starts from 3 nodes away from the roor then your algo don't work. you are checking with root node only. if loop in list include root node then it is fine otherwise not.

Comment: I corrected my code for better way of presenting question. thanks.

Comment: A simpler formulation of this algorithm would be `while (fast != null) { if (fast == root) return true; } return false;`, when you remove the `slow` pointer checking `.next.next` is basically just unrolling the loop manually. I'd also rename `fast` while I'm at it.

Comment: If you wanted speed, you would use an array as a circular buffer and this problem would be trivial. Note: this is how network adapters work.  It's a bit like saying, how can I make this slow thing a bit faster without using the proper data structure for this problem.

Comment: @DavidPrun, but (as delnan points out) that won't work anyway, if your starting point is outside the loop. It doesn't matter squat if it's actually the head of the list of not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works when you're starting from inside the cycle. However, the following is also a valid circular list:

```
N1 --> N2 --> N3 --> N4
       ^             v
       +-------------+
```

Your algorithm works when starting from N2, N3 or N4, but not when starting from N1.

Comment: delnan, I appreciate your response, this enlightened me..

Comment: I think delnan is right. @DavidPrun You always checking against the same "someRandomNodeOfList". If the "someRandomNodeOfList" is out of the circle then you will end up in a infinite loop without finding an answer.    For more info refer this.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare

Answer (score 1):

### Failure to solve the challenge

The problem in *Cracking the Coding Interview* asks to find not only *whether* the list contains a cycle, but *where* the cycle begins.

### Failure to compile

Since `while (true) { … }` is an infinite loop, the `while true;` at the end is unreachable code, which is a compilation error in Java.

Since `while (true)` is always a kind of a lie, it would have been better to rewrite the loop as:

```
while (fast.next != null && fast.next.next != null) {
    if (fast.next == someRandomNodeOfList || fast.next.next == someRandomNodeOfList) {
        return true;
    }
    fast = fast.next.next;
}
return false;
```

### Why unroll the loop?

Advancing two links at a time (`fast = fast.next.next;`) is unconventional.  What you are really doing is performing the work of two conventional loop iterations in one iteration.  The normal way to write that is much easier to understand:

```
for (Node fast = someRandomNodeOfList; fast.next != null; fast = fast.next) {
    if (fast.next == someRandomNodeOfList) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Perhaps that formulation makes it easier to see the bug that @delnan spotted.